# How to print Groovy list and keep the quotes?

Tags: string, list, groovy, concatenation

We have a list:

```
List test = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

I don't want to alter this list hardcoded, since it has many items.

When printing this like:

```
println "${test}"
```

We get `[a, b, c]` but I want to have `["a", "b", "c"]`

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the issue that you face actually?

Comment: Passing a groovy command as a String from master to slave.

Comment: Can't you pass list instead of string?

Comment: Yes and no, we pass a command as String to the Slave node to be executed there. So when we loop trough this list on the main node it goes fine, but when defining a loop inside this string, it tries to loop over [a, b, c] and not a list of strings anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can try representing your list as `String` by joining all elements like this:

```
List test = ["a", "b", "c"]

String listAsString =  "[\"${test.join('", "')}\"]"

println listAsString
```

#### Output

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```

It join all elements using `", "` and adds `["` in the beginning and `"]` in the end of the string.

Answer (score 8):

Groovy has `inspect()` for *better* output (closer to input, but be aware, that this is no proper way to serialize Groovy datastructures):

```
Groovy Shell (2.5.0-beta-1, JVM: 1.8.0_152)
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
groovy:000> test = ["a", "b", "c"]
===> [a, b, c]
groovy:000> test.inspect()
===> ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

Comment: When: println "${test.inspect()}" we still get [a, b, c]

Comment: What Groovy version you use? `2.4.12` returns the output @cfrick shown.

Comment: I have not whitnessed a groovy version, that does that.  Most likely something else strips the single quotes out onwards.

Answer (score 0):

You might join items in the list with `", "` it should give you somthing like this `a", "b", "c`. Then just add string `["` from the left and string `"]` from the right to get what you need - `["a", "b", "c"]`.
See code example below.

```
def List l = ["a","b","c"]
def String s = '["' + l.join('", "') + '"]'
print s
```

output

```
["a", "b", "c"]
```